# Windows Peer-to-Peer SDK Statistics

Tags: windows, sdk, p2p

Does anyone happen to have any throughput and speed statistics on the Windows SDK? I am attempting to do a comparative analysis of this to other P2P implementations and can not for the life of me find any form of statistical data on this SDK.

Comment: Perhaps because the windows SDK doesn't do any kind of P2P ? I mean, unless you count the ability to open files over SMB or open a socket or something.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/p2p/
here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/peertopeer/threads/
and here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545868.aspx